# Bootstrap typeahead and quoted string

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am having the same issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5646)

```
<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Amsterdam", "Maastricht"]' />

does work, but when using double quotes like

<input type="text" class="span3" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="['Amsterdam', 'Maastricht']" />

it won't work.
```

I infact uses it with Angular + Angular-ui

```
<input type="text" ng-model="mymodel" placeholder="Cities.."
                ui-jq="typeahead" ui-options="{source:cities}"/>

$scope.cities =["D","A"]
```

Typeahead works if I change it to

```
$scope.cities =['D','A']
```

Do I need to convert my array with double quoted string? How. Is there a way to do this by [native json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON).

thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular-UI, but it almost sounds like it's doing a replacement of $eval'ed items in that ui-options attribute... so you end up with something like `ui-options="{source:["D","A"]}"` which wouldn't work because of the unexpected quotes.... I'm just guessing, but that's pretty weird. Have you considered just making your own custom directive? It shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: THanks. With your hint, I changed to ui-options='{source:cities}', and which solved the problem. YOu may add it as an answer, so I can accept. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Angular-UI, but it almost sounds like it's doing a replacement of $eval'ed items in that ui-options attribute... so you end up with something like `ui-options="{source:["D","A"]}"`

EDIT: So like you said in your comment, wrap it in single quotes.